# update url with anchor tag without jumping to tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made this auto url anchor tag script that generates a link to the site and jumps to the article where the url was taken from.
It works fine but when I scroll past a headline and the url is updated it snaps to the anchor tag. So my question is, is it possible to make it not snap and just behave as normal scroll (test snippet)

```js
    var url = "";
    var anchor = "";
    var element1 = "";
    var element2 = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        url = window.location.href;
    });
    
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {       
            var findMiddleElement = (function (docElm) {
                var viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight,                   
                    elements = $('.subheading');
                return function (e) {
                    var middleElement;
                    if (e && e.type == 'resize')
                        viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight;
                    elements.each(function () {
                        var pos = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                        if (pos > viewportHeight / 2.5 && pos < viewportHeight / 1.5) {
                            middleElement = this;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    element1 = middleElement;
                    if (element1 != element2) {
                        element2 = element1;
                        anchor = $(middleElement).text();
                        if (anchor != "") {                            
                            window.location.href = url + "#" + anchor;
                        }                            
                    }                                        
                }
            })(document.documentElement);
            $(window).on('scroll resize', findMiddleElement);            
        });
    });
```

```css
p{
padding: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='subheading'><a name='test1'/>test1</p>
<p class='subheading'><a name='test2'/>test2</p>
<p class='subheading'><a name='test3'/>test3</p>
<p class='subheading'><a name='test4'/>test4</p>
<p class='subheading'><a name='test5'/>test5</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/akrion/rLdkzn53/129/)

I changed this so that the movement is smoother:

```
if (anchor != "") {
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: $(middleElement).offset().top - 100
  }, 1000);
}
```

the `-100` is a small offset since it keeps scrolling until it reaches the end otherwise. You can figure out the exact numbers etc. But that is the idea.